# Ubuntu 20.04 with X710 Intel Network card not recognised

Tags: networking, 20.04, intel

I have an X710 dual 10Gbps SPF+ card made by Intel, it is not properly recognised by Ubuntu 20.04

I don't really know how to get it to work, does anyone know how to overcome this?

```
# lspci | grep X710
43:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ (rev 02)
43:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ (rev 02)

ethtool enp67s0f0
Settings for enp67s0f0:
    Supported ports: [ ]
    Supported link modes:   Not reported
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Other
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no

# uname -r
5.15.0-48-generic

root@charles:~# lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1521] (rev 01)
    DeviceName:  Intel i350-AM2
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. I350 Gigabit Network Connection [1043:853b]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
--
01:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1521] (rev 01)
    DeviceName:  Intel i350-AM2
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. I350 Gigabit Network Connection [1043:853b]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
--
43:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ [8086:1572] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Converged Network Adapter X710-2 [8086:0007]
    Kernel driver in use: i40e
    Kernel modules: i40e
43:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+ [8086:1572] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Converged Network Adapter X710 [8086:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: i40e
    Kernel modules: i40e

$ sudo lshw -C network | grep -B5 enp67s0f
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:43:00.0
       logical name: enp67s0f0
--
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:43:00.1
       logical name: enp67s0f1

# dmesg | grep -e enp67 -e i40e
[    2.870003] i40e: Intel(R) Ethernet Connection XL710 Network Driver
[    2.877424] i40e: Copyright (c) 2013 - 2019 Intel Corporation.
[    2.907461] i40e 0000:43:00.0: fw 6.0.48442 api 1.7 nvm 6.01 0x800035cf 1.1747.0 [8086:1572] [8086:0007]
[    2.992889] i40e 0000:43:00.0: MAC address: 40:a6:b7:95:81:8c
[    2.999281] i40e 0000:43:00.0: FW LLDP is enabled
[    3.028430] i40e 0000:43:00.0: PCI-Express: Speed 8.0GT/s Width x8
[    3.049573] i40e 0000:43:00.0: Features: PF-id[0] VFs: 64 VSIs: 66 QP: 64 RSS FD_ATR FD_SB NTUPLE DCB VxLAN Geneve PTP VEPA
[    3.076016] i40e 0000:43:00.1: fw 6.0.48442 api 1.7 nvm 6.01 0x800035cf 1.1747.0 [8086:1572] [8086:0007]
[    3.190486] i40e 0000:43:00.1: MAC address: 40:a6:b7:95:81:8d
[    3.204780] i40e 0000:43:00.1: FW LLDP is enabled
[    3.235347] i40e 0000:43:00.1: PCI-Express: Speed 8.0GT/s Width x8
[    3.244233] i40e 0000:43:00.1: Features: PF-id[1] VFs: 64 VSIs: 66 QP: 64 RSS FD_ATR FD_SB NTUPLE DCB VxLAN Geneve PTP VEPA
[    3.359453] i40e 0000:43:00.0 enp67s0f0: renamed from eth0
[    3.621598] i40e 0000:43:00.1 enp67s0f1: renamed from eth1

# sudo modprobe -r i40e && sudo modprobe i40e
# ethtool enp67s0f0
Settings for enp67s0f0:
    Supported ports: [  ]
    Supported link modes:   Not reported
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Auto-negotiation: off
    Port: Other
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Supports Wake-on: d
    Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `uname -r` and also: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: How did you verify that enp67s0f0 is one of the 10GB cards? With `sudo lshw -C network` ?

Comment: yes - added to post.

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `sudo dmesg | grep -e enp67 -e i40e`

Comment: Is the ethtool result any different after: `sudo modprobe -r i40e && sudo modprobe i40e`?

Comment: still same - added

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am also facing the same issue till now.

Comment: yes, i removed the card and put in a different network card ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a proprietary driver from [drivers for xl710](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/details/ethernet/700-controllers/xl710-controllers/downloads.html)

Comment: i did install these drivers, but it made no difference to the output of ethtool. :(